# Program that returns words that ends and starts with the same letter

Tags: c

I have problem with my alignement. This time I want my program to return words that ends and starts with the same letter. I've wrote something like this, but it seems to return random words.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char str[100];
    int i, t, j, len;

    printf("Enter a string : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str);

    len = strlen(str);
    str[len] = ' ';

    for (t = 0, i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] == ' ') && (str[i - 1] == str[0]))
        {
            for (j = t; j < i; j++)
                printf("%c", str[j]);
            t = i + 1;
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if (str[i] == ' ')
            {
                t = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use strtok() to tokenize the initial string with delimiter ' ' and then use an if then else clause that will look like this.  char * test = "abcdefgha";
 if (test[0] == test[strlen(test) - 1]) cout << test; I didn't even look at your loops code logic. And just a tip, don't try to reinvent the wheel every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to split the strings from `stdin`, then apply a letter checker on each parsed word one at a time.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXCHAR 100

int is_start_end(char *word);
void exit_if_null(void *ptr, const char *msg);

int
main(void) {
    char str[MAXCHAR];
    char *word;
    char **all_words;
    int words_size = 1, word_count = 0;
    int i, found;

    all_words = malloc(words_size * sizeof(*all_words));
    exit_if_null(all_words, "initial Allocation");

    printf("Enter words(enter empty line to terminate):\n");
    while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, stdin) != NULL && strlen(str) != 1) {
        word = strtok(str, " \n");

        while (word !=NULL) {
            if (words_size == word_count) {
                words_size *= 2;
                all_words = realloc(all_words, words_size * sizeof(*all_words));
                exit_if_null(all_words, "Reallocation");
            }
            all_words[word_count] = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
            exit_if_null(all_words[word_count], "Initial Allocation");

            strcpy(all_words[word_count], word);

            word_count++;

            word = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
    }

    printf("Words that have equal first and last letters:\n");

    found = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
        if (is_start_end(all_words[i])) {
            found = 1;
            printf("%s\n", all_words[i]);
        }
        free(all_words[i]);
        all_words[i] = NULL;
    }

    if (found == 0) {
        printf("None Found\n");
    }

    free(all_words);
    all_words = NULL;

    return 0;
}

int
is_start_end(char *word) {
    int len;

    len = strlen(word);

    if ((len == 1) || (tolower(word[0]) == tolower(word[len-1]))) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void
exit_if_null(void *ptr, const char *msg) {
    if (!ptr) {
        printf("Unexpected null pointer: %s\n", msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line removes the null terminator of the string:

```
len = strlen(str);
str[len] = ' ';
```

thus the string no longer exists, what is left is just an ordinary array of characters.

The next call to strlen, in the body of the for loop, will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @Struziu There are multiple problems with the code. I suggest you step through the code and find them.

Comment: Oh, i see. Program compares last char of the words with first char of a whole line. Am i right?